# NGINX equivalent to Apache mod_rewrite's noescape

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to migrate a server from Apache to NGINX.  It sits in front of an S3 bucket to provide access control and some URL rewriting.  I was able to switch everything over except this one weird rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^+]*)\+\+(.*)$ http://s3.amazonaws.com/bucket$1\%2b\%2b$2 [P,NE]
```

We have a one file that needs to have "++" in the URL.  When you request it from S3 the +'s need to be URL escaped.  The noescape flag lets you do this in Apache.  I tried to do this in NGINX as:

```
rewrite ^([^+]*)\+\+(.*)$ $1%2b%2b$2 last;
```

but the percent signs get double escaped and "++" was replaced with "%252b%252b".  Is there any way to do this with NGINX?

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping % with another %:

```
rewrite ^([^+]*)\+\+(.*)$ $1%%2b%%2b$2 last;
```

Comment: No luck.  That gets translated to "%25%25b%25%25b"